# ADO Pipeline Test result attachment api failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate

I am trying to get the attachment from a pipeline test result using following steps via Power Automate

1. Get all the test results

   GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/ResultDetailsByBuild?buildId={buildID}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/ResultDetailsByBuild?buildId=%7BbuildID%7D)
2. Filter the failed test cases
3. Get the attachment using this url

   GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runID}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/Attachments/1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Runs/%7BrunID%7D/Results/%7BtestCaseResultId%7D/Attachments/1)

This is always giving me an error "Not Found" but if manually open the test case once and see the attachment once and then run these apis it starts working

can anyone please help me with this issue